# pushViewController causes memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uinavigationcontroller

The Leaks application tells me that the following function is causing a memory leak and I can't figure out why.

```
-(void)viewGameList {
GameListController *gameListViewController = [[GameListController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameListController" bundle:nil];
gameListViewController.rootController = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gameListViewController animated:YES];
[gameListViewController release];
```

}

It tells me that this line causes a 128 byte memory leak.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gameListViewController animated:YES];
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: How is the property `.rootController` declared?

Comment: I'm not sure if the code will show up correctly in a comment, but this is the answer to your question from GameListController.m :

@class RootViewController;

@interface GameListController : UIViewController {
 RootViewController *rootController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) RootViewController *rootController;

Any ideas as to why I'd be getting a memory leak here?

Answer (score 1):

One rule about iPhone memory management.

- Child object must never retain its parent.

So, don't use **retain** in property declaration, use **assign** instead.